# Cannot import UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, import, uikit

I'm trying to create a school project but I can't seem to find an answer to an error I am having.

For some reason I can't compile my code because there is a fatal error that reads : "No such module as 'UIKit'". It worked previously on other projects but I have no idea why it isn't working for this one. Any ideas?

Thank you so much!

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var CCAWebView: UIWebView?
    @IBOutlet var MoongateWebView: UIWebView?
    @IBOutlet var ManagebacWebView: UIWebView?
    @IBOutlet var MoodleWebView: UIWebView?
    @IBOutlet var LibraryWebView: UIWebView?
    @IBOutlet var gmailWebView: UIWebView?
    @IBOutlet var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordField: UITextField!




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


// all the code for portal screen starts here
        //loading for Moongate on the screen
        if let _ = MoongateWebView {
            let mgurl = NSURL(string: "http://moongate.cis.edu.hk/")
            let mgrequest = NSURLRequest(URL: mgurl!)
            MoongateWebView!.loadRequest(mgrequest)
            }

       //loading Managebac on the screen

        if let _ = ManagebacWebView {
            let mburl = NSURL(string: "https://cishk.managebac.com/login")
            let mbrequest = NSURLRequest(URL: mburl!)
            ManagebacWebView!.loadRequest(mbrequest)
        }


        //loading Moodle on the screen

        if let _ = MoodleWebView {
            let mdurl = NSURL(string: "http://moodle.cis.edu.hk/moodle/")
            let mdrequest = NSURLRequest(URL: mdurl!)
            MoodleWebView!.loadRequest(mdrequest)

        }
        //loading Library on the screen

        if let _ = LibraryWebView {
                let liburl = NSURL(string: "http://library.cis.edu.hk/")
                let librequest = NSURLRequest(URL: liburl!)
                LibraryWebView!.loadRequest(librequest)
        }


        //loading CCAs on the screen

        if let _ = CCAWebView {
            let ccaurl = NSURL(string: "http://moongate.cis.edu.hk/content/page.aspx?e=F17A69B3-62F1-46FF-A474-8776C2D2492D")
            let ccarequest = NSURLRequest(URL: ccaurl!)
            CCAWebView!.loadRequest(ccarequest)
        }

        //loading gmail on the screen

        if let _ = gmailWebView {
            let gmailurl = NSURL(string: "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/")
            let gmailrequest = NSURLRequest(URL: gmailurl!)
            gmailWebView!.loadRequest(gmailrequest)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you created an *iOS* project?

Comment: Go to your target's `Build Phases` -> `Link Binary With Libraries` section and check that UIKit.framework is in the list

Comment: @alexburtnik Thank you for your comment! When I try to search up the library I can't find UIKit.framework... Is InterfaceBuilderKit.framework the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

If UIKit isn't in your "Link Binary With Libraries" framework list, it's possible that you may have accidentally deleted the framework from Xcode. I've done it before with Core Graphics. Have you been fiddling around with Xcode's internal files? If you have, it's possible that you deleted the framework in its entirety from your computer.

Check `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks`. Do you see UIKit in there? If not, you deleted it, so you should reinstall it by finding a copy online, or you can just reinstall Xcode.